# Chinese Remainder Theorem when the moduli is not pairwise coprime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

On my textbook, after the proof of the Chinese Remainder Theorem when the moduli is pairwise relatively prime, one modification is left as exercise.

Prove that the system of linear congruences $x\equiv a_i\pmod{m_i}$ is solvable if and only if $gcd(m_i,m_j) \vert (a_i - a_j)$ for all $i\neq j$, and $i,j \in \{ 1,2,\dots r \} .$ (or $a_i\equiv a_j\mod{gcd(m_i,m_j)}$ which is the same). If a solution exists, it is unique $\mod{lcm(m_1,m_2,...,m_r)}$

I managed to find a proof for the case $r=2$, and from there tried to do induction, but I am stuck when I have to use the inductive hypothesis.

$[ \longrightarrow ]$

Suppose that $a_i\equiv a_j\mod{(m_i,m_j)}$ for all $i\neq j$, and $i,j \in \{ 1,2,\dots,r, r+1 \}$.

Then, the system

$$ x\equiv a_1 \mod{m_1} \\  
x\equiv a_2 \mod{m_2}\\ 
.\\.\\.\\
x\equiv a_r \mod{m_r}\\
$$

has a solutions, lets say $b$ (by inductive hypohesis).

I will next like to consider the system

$$
x\equiv b \mod{lcm(m_1,m_2,...,m_3)}\\ x\equiv a_{r+1} \mod{m_{r+1}} 
$$

and find that it has a solution using the case $r=2$, but I don't know how to use my hyphotesis here because I need $b \equiv m_{r+1}\mod{gcd(lcm(m_1,m_2,...,m_r),m_{r+1}))}$

$[\longleftarrow]$: As for the converse I don't know how to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x\equiv b$ is a solution to the first system, $b\equiv a_i \ mod \ m_i$.
Note that $a_i \equiv a_{r+1} \ mod \ gcd(m_i,m_{r+1})$ and $gcd(m_i,m_{r+1})$ divides $m_i$, we get: $$b\equiv a_i \equiv a_{r+1} \ mod \ gcd(m_i,m_{r+1})$$
for all $1 \leq i \leq r$.
Then, $$b \equiv a_{r+1}\mod \ lcm(gcd(m_1,m_{r+1}),...,gcd(m_r,m_{r+1}))=A $$
Now it remains to show that $A$ is divisible by $B=gcd(lcm(m_1,...,m_r),m_{r+1})$
Let $p$ be any prime number, we'll show that $v_p(A) \geq v_p(B)$, where $v_p(x)$ is the multiplicity of $p$ in the prime factorization of $x$.
We can check that $v_p(A)$ is the largest number in $min(v_p(m_i),v_p(m_{r+1}))$ where $1 \leq i \leq r$
and $v_p(B)$ is the smaller number between $max(v_p(m_1),...,v_p(m_r))$ and $v_p(m_{r+1})$
There're only two cases:
$\textbf{Case 1}$: $v_p(m_{r+1}) \gt v_p(m_i)$ for all $1 \leq i \leq r$
Then $v_p(A)$ the largest number in $v_p(m_1),...,v_p(m_r)$ i.e $v_p(A)=max(v_p(m_1),...,v_p(m_r))$
$v_p(m_{r+1}) \gt max(v_p(m_1),...,v_p(m_r)) $ so $v_p(B)=max(v_p(m_1),...,v_p(m_r)) $
$\textbf{Case 2}$: $\exists \ 1 \leq k \leq r: v_p(m_{r+1}) \leq v_p(m_k)$
Then $v_p(A) \geq v_p(m_{r+1}) $ because $min(v_p(m_k),v_p(m_{r+1}))=v_p(m_{r+1})$
$v_p(B)=v_p(m_{r+1})$ because $v_p(m_{r+1}) \leq v_p(m_k) \leq max(v_p(m_1),...,v_p(m_r)) $
In both cases, $v_p(A) \geq v_p(B)$ so $B$ divides $A$ and we're done.
The converse is actually much easier, assume that $x \equiv b \ mod \ lcm(m_1,...,m_r)$ is a solution.
Then $b \equiv a_i \ mod \ m_i$, $  b \equiv a_j \ mod \ m_j$ for all $1 \leq i \lt j \leq r$
But $gcd(m_i,m_j)$ divides both $m_i$ and $m_j$ so $gcd(m_i,m_j)$ divides $(a_i-b)+(b-a_j)=a_i-a_j$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).